# TUN/TAP VPN no internet connection

Tags: ssh, vpn, tun, tap

I have set up a tun/tap vpn to a VPS. For this, I created a 10/24 network and gave the server the IP 10.0.0.100 and my client got 10.0.0.200.

I can now successfully ping the server / access my mail server etc using the 10.0.0.100 address, so all is working well so far.

My issue comes when I try to connect to the net through my VPN. I'm not sure how to do this since my VPS only has one IPv4 address allocated to it (it is not part of a subnet so I cannot add my client to the subnet and use the servers default gateway to get to the internet).

Can anyone point me in the right direction to get all traffic from my client to route through my VPS and be able to connect to the internet?

By the way, I have a number of IPv6 address' allocated to my VPS, but I don't know if this will be of any use.

Thanks!
Nick